# Why the first argument of fread() be cast to other type in

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

Here is the program:

```
FILE *fp;
struct record rec;
while (fread((char *)&rec, sizeof(rec), 1, fp) == 1) // Here
{
    /* do something to rec */
    if (/*rec must be rewritten*/) 
    {
        fseek(fp, -(long)sizeof(rec), 1);
        fwrite((char*)&rec, sizeof(rec), 1, fp);  // And here
    }
}
```

Look at the notes, the author says:

> It looks reasonable enough at first glance: `&rec` is carefully cast to `char *` to pass to `fread` and `fwrite`...

I can't understand the meaning.

Comment: Neither do I. There's no need for the cast: the first argument of `fread()` is of type `void *`. You could as well just pass in `&rec` without any problem.

Comment: I'm assuming that the extra asterisks are there to highlight the cast... not a great idea.  I'd remove them.  They're unnecessary and look like a compiler error.

Comment: c loser, perhaps the author meant that 'he was typing very softly' when he said 'carefully cast'?

Comment: Where did you get this from? [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) have a `void*` as first argument, meaning it can take *any* kind of pointer. No casting needed.

Comment: C Traps And Pitfalls---Chapter5.2

Comment: c Traps and Pitfalls is very, very old. I threw mine out decades ago. From what I remember, changes to the c language and compilers - such as the introduction of void* - have made much of it irrelevent

Comment: This cast was required in pre-ANSI code, maybe it is very old source.  The use of `fseek` is non-portable too.

Comment: The book is 25 years old. Looks like pre-ANSI. Do you have a computer history museum nearby? Would make a good home for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't attempt to use SO `**` markup inside code blocks. It doesn't work as intended and it only creates confusion.

Secondly, the book is apparently outdated. Back in the very old versions of C language there was no `void *` type and `char *` type was typically used instead as "generic" pointer type. The first parameter of `fread` was declared with `char *` type. For this reason it was customary to perform explicit cast of actual argument type to `char *` to avoid compiler warnings. It might even be necessary today, if an old version of standard library is used (one that declares `fread` with `char *` parameter).

Modern C standard library declares `fread` with first parameter of type `void *`. No cast is necessary in that case and cast to `char *` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks，I was posted first time,I will pay attention to the format next time.